# My CSS file in Github isn't being used by the HTML file

Tags: html, css, file, github

This is the link: https://footballcoder.github.io/YearOfCode/projects/about.html (source code: https://github.com/FootballCoder/YearOfCode)

If you see in my repo, I have a folder called projects and in there I have my about.html, and a folder called css. I have a file in the css subfolder that is called about.css, which is the css for about.html. I don't know why the css isn't being used. Is it the way the file is being linked or some other error. The link from the HTML file is in the  tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/projects/css/about.css">
```

to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/about.css">
```

I hope this [article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) can help you

Comment: Oh my god!! It worked!! Thank you so much, I spent FOREVER trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to the link as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/projects/css/about.css" />
```

See if the following edit (removing '/projects/') fixes the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about.css" />
```

This should work because it is linking the path starting at the serving html, aka about.html, not at the root of your site. Just tested it with Dev Tools in Chrome, and it looks like it works (and is super cool!)

Side note: if your fonts from Google aren't loading, move the custom CSS below those links in the head. I'm not sure if they are or not since I'm not familiar with them, but that will work if that is also an issue.